# Angular 2 http post to my laravel API

Tags: laravel, angular

Let's say I have the following Laravel `store()` method:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
        $Hero = new Hero;
        $Hero->name = $request->name;
        $Hero->description = $request->description;
        $Hero->save();
    }
```

And it's route `Route::post('newhero', 'HeroController@store');`

I want to use Angular 2 to POST data to the above method when user clicks a button. My data is not coming from a form.

My angular method:

```
addHero(hero) {
    let body = "name=" + hero.name + "&description=" + hero.description;
    let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        this.http
    .post('http://localhost/heroland/public/api/v1/newhero', 
      body, {
        headers: headers
      })
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      response => this.data;
    );
    }
```

Angular posts the data, and I get the following error in the laravel POST:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `heroes` (`name`, description`,`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , 2016-04-10 17:10:09, 2016-04-10 17:10:09))
```

Seem like something is wrong with my `body` variable, but  I have no idea how it should be.
Any help?

My request:

```
POST /myURL/ HTTP/1.1
Accept:          */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:      keep-alive
Content-Length:  38
Content-Type:    text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cookie:          XSRF-TOKEN=myToken
Host:            localhost
Origin:          http://localhost:3000
Referer:         http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36

name=1&description=100
```

Comment: The error basically speaks for itself; it appears that your hero object lacks a name value! Can you verify that you have that right?

Comment: This is right 100%.  I used console.log(hero.name) and it showed my value.

Comment: Yeah but can you please log the value of body? or var_dump the request value for name in your php function>

Comment: The body variables are good, just tested it. For some reasons my angular method send empty data to my laravel or $request->name is wrong(?). I can't check the $request in the laravel side, there is no way to log or output it I guess

Comment: What is the value of this.data?

Comment: The value of this.data is undefined

Comment: You can var_dump(request->name); exit;

Comment: I have successfully logged my request, update my question with my request output

Comment: Why your request contains Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 instead application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: I have changed my angular post to JSON and the header to JSON and it worked! Thanks yurzui for the point!!

Answer (score 0):

You could have forgotten to import the `Headers` class. This way the `Content-Type` header isn't sent and your service wouldn't able to deserialize the form since it wouldn't know that the payload is actually a form.

```
import {Http, Headers, ...} from 'angular2/http';
```

Comment: Yep I had no Headers imported, but seem like it didn't solve my problem. My data is still sent empty to my laravel method.

Comment: What kind of content do you expect? Url encoded form, json content or query parameters?

Comment: I tried this post body too: `let body = {
    name: hero.name,
    description: hero.description
  };` with no success